# Redirect path set via java actionforward not in struts

Tags: java, redirect, path, struts

Hi and thanks in advance.

i need to redirect to a website but there will be a few choices. so depending on the choice i want to redirect to that specific website. however i do not want do do it via struts. here is the java part:

```
    if(token == null){
        ActionRedirect redirect = new ActionRedirect(mapping.findForward(FWD_REDIRECT));
         redirect.addParameter("id","123");
         redirect.addParameter("name","aaa");
         redirect.addParameter("surname","sss");
         redirect.setPath("http://www.yahoo.com");
    }
```

and here is the struts part:

```
    <forward name="redirect" path="" redirect="true" />
```

i want to know what i can put on path in struts to get it to go to the redirect.setPath("http://www.yahoo.com").

once again thank you in advance ;)

Comment: I thought you said you didn't want to do it via Struts.

Comment: i dont want to have the redirect path on struts, as the options will not be known. it will be read of an object elsewhere and the address would be extracted. this will be unknown to me. but the way everything else is implemented is by using the action forward which goes through struts. sorry for the confusion.